# how to remove a directory from a apk file without unzipping?

Tags: android, apk, aapt

for certain business purpose I need to remove a certain directory from an apk file. e.g. remove lib/mips64.

this process does not allow me to unzip the apk (re-packaging an apk file using zip would make it corrupted) prior to any file operations.

I tried the "aapt remove" command but it didn't work out on directories, and I didn't find any other modifier that could do the job.

Any ideas?

---

later I found out that the directory would be removed after all files inside are removed. kinda smart :)

Comment: you need to try this: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423

Comment: @thepoosh I didn't find anything related to aapt there, which part of the doc were you referring?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove a file or folder from a given APK with the following command (where "META-INF" is the folder in this example):

```
zip -d your.apk "META-INF/*"
```

To make sure that the file/folder is deleted, you can run this command:

```
unzip -l your.apk
```

It will show a table like this on your terminal. It doesn't contain the folder which I deleted:

```
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
     2284  08-13-2018 17:49   AndroidManifest.xml
      916  08-13-2018 17:49   res/layout/activity_main.xml
     3418  08-13-2018 17:49   res/mipmap-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png
     4208  08-13-2018 17:49   res/mipmap-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher_round.png
     2206  08-13-2018 17:49   res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png
     2555  08-13-2018 17:49   res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher_round.png
     4842  08-13-2018 17:49   res/mipmap-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png
     6114  08-13-2018 17:49   res/mipmap-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher_round.png
     7718  08-13-2018 17:49   res/mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png
    10056  08-13-2018 17:49   res/mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher_round.png
    10486  08-13-2018 17:49   res/mipmap-xxxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png
    14696  08-13-2018 17:49   res/mipmap-xxxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher_round.png
     2552  08-13-2018 17:49   resources.arsc
     4716  08-13-2018 17:49   classes.dex
---------                     -------
    76767                     14 files
```

Comment: but it would not work without sign key for repacking.

Comment: @Yeung I don't recall how it used to work since it's an old answer. However, I assume that the only issue would be when installing over a genuine app (i.e. when upgrading because the signing key is different). Other than that, it should work fine.